por que cada ves que quiero insertar datos a una tabla o al crear una vista en Oracle me sale el error de identificador invalido si mi id esta bien
Error SQL: ORA-00904: "ID_VIAJE": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! si no vemos que intentas, no podemos ayudarte.. usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion necesaria para que veamos lo mismo que vos

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
